# ODBC driver cannot read rows added in Excel

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, odbc

I create `xls/xlsx` file from C# using ODBC (with `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`). The result table has 4 rows (for example). I open the file with Excel, add 5-th row and save the file. When try to read it from C# over ODBC with `SELECT * FROM [table]` I get only the original 4 rows without 5th. It seems ODBC stores somewhere in XLS file the number of rows and later reads only them without new data entered from Excel or LibreOffice. Is this known problem and can I solve it? If I create new spreadsheet in Excel, all its rows are read fron C#.

EDIT: I found some useful information. When the XLS file is first created from C#/ODBC, there are 2 tables (sheets). If the table name is TABLE, `DataTable sheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null)` will contain `sheets.Rows[0]` == "TABLE" and `sheets.Rows[1]` == "TABLE$". Excel will show only one sheet "TABLE". After edit the changes (5th row) exist only in "TABLE$" sheet.

Comment: Check spreadsheet specific row value maybe there's unnecessary extra character that's why it's refused to save.

Comment: Without seeing any code makes it difficult to help. Do you do a refresh on the ODBC connection : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.odbcconnection.refresh.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I found the problem. It seems that internal spreadsheet names created by Excel have "$" sign at the end. The sheet name generated by ODBC are the exact string given in `CREATE TABLE`. On the other hand, Excel (and LibreOffice) show only one sheet for both `TABLE` and `TABLE$` sheets. If I edit the table in Excel, after save the changes are only in `TABLE$`. The other sheet `TABLE` is unchanged. When I do `SELECT * FROM [TABLE]` the result is from the original ODBC generated table without Excel changes. Now I enumerate the available sheets inside XLS file and if first sheet name does not end with "$" and sheets are more than 1, I add "$" to first sheet name and open the correct table. I suppose ODBC connection string may include option to work with "$"-ending tables...

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the 5th row by code if yes, could you please share the code lines which you are using for doing the same. There might be following issue in your code.

1. Save commit not done properly.
2. Before reading the file connection refresh not done.

Comment: 5th row is added in Excel, not in C#. Then C# with ODBC reads only first 4 rows. I know ODBC has cache feature but not sure whether the cache is on HDD / temp file or somehow in XLS file. Every row stored from C# is then read in C#.